# php install extension effect

Tags: php, linux

I am just curious about the process of installing an extension because I am trying to install php's [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) extension on Ubuntu. I have a default php installation in my usr/ directory, but I have a XAMPP server set up (separate php apache mysql package) in another location in /opt. This is the installation I use for testing.

When I use the command `pecl install uploadprogress`, the extension installs automatically to the /usr directory. As a test I took the `uploadprogress.so` file out of the /usr directory php location and put it in the opt location where my XAMPP installation is. I then modified the php.ini for my XAMPP installation and put the extension in. When I ran phpinfo() it showed uploadprogress as installed, however when uploading a file, the uploadprogress function returns null.

**My question is, when a php extension is installed, what processes are done, and what files are created and modified?** If I manually download the uploadprogress.tgz and manually compile, it still installs to the default directory of /usr/local/php5/ext and I figure there must be more done then just a .so file created in the extension directory. **How can I change the location that the extension installs to?** I want to have the extension available to my other XAMPP installation in /opt.

Comment: If it shows up in `phpinfo()` it should be working. Did you restart your XAMPP after moving the file?

Comment: Yes I did. Is the .so file all that is created though from installing an extension? Is the php installation recompiled as well or something? It shows up because I just copied the .so file to the ext directory of my other installation and then put the extension in my php.ini file but I figure there must be something else I should do to make the installation complete.

Comment: Are you calling the function as `uploadprogress($id);` or `uploadprogress_get_info($id);`? In the examples they use `uploadprogress_get_info($id);`. Other than that I'm not sure. But I'm 99% sure the extension is just the single .so file.

Comment: I am posting the form with a unique id and use jquery $.getJSON("testing1234.php?id=" + progress_key, function(data) { to ping a file which contains echo json_encode(uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['id']));

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know it was just an .so file so I did not go around trying to mod the installation process. Jquery returns a null result so I do not know what is going on. I thought maybe it was not installed properly.

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps this link will help you a little bit: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php-config.php

Comment: Thanks I was able to properly install it but now I just need to get this silly extension to work!!! It keeps returning null. Have no idea why. Do you know of any settings specific for this extension?

Comment: ok I got it working. I tried a large file and the first return was basically to say the upload had completed and the following responses were null. It is kind of annoying however that I cannot simulate online behavior with this extension on my localserver. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to here you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, when a php extension is installed, what processes are done, and what files are created and modified?

That depends on the extension, but normally there is the building and compilation of the extension. Temporary files are created, the configuration could getting modified and the actual module file (.so/.dll) is getting written (at least).

Keep in mind that some modules require certain settings in php.ini before they work. If you have copied over only the `.so` file then you should copy over the relevant part of the `php.ini` as well.

> How can I change the location that the extension installs to?

You normally compile it for the location you want to install it to. If the default location is not the location you want it to be, you can try to specify the output directory in the build process, and there is [php-config](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php-config.php).

Comment: Thanks hakre I specified the right php-config when compiling and it installed properly. The extension function uploadprogress_get_info however returns null yet it shows up as installed in phpinfo(). I know this is unrelated kind of but do you know from experience of any specific settings that would cause the extension uploadprogress to do this?

Comment: No, not from the top of my head. Check the extensions docs and google.

Comment: I think it may be because I am using a local testing server and the file pretty much uploads instantly. I tried a large file and the first return was basically to say the upload had completed and the following responses were null. It is kind of annoying however that I cannot simulate online behavior with this extension on my localserver. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure you can. Just throttle the bandwidth. I think there is an apache module for that so you can better simulate real-life on your test-system.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run configure --help to see what options it gives to you to compile the extension and to look for the install directory path option. Maybe this answer helps you with pecl [How do you change the default Pear/PECL build folder from /var/tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096980/how-do-you-change-the-default-pear-pecl-build-folder-from-var-tmp). A .so file is a special standalone library. It's stripped from any linkage and is basically an object file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jitamaro. Appreciate it.